# <td> tag ignores the width that i've setted

Tags: html-table, doctype

I've created this table that's well formatted in chrome but in ie8 the < td> tag ignores the percentages that i've setted, then if i add table-layout:fixed as someone suggested ie8 ignores the proportion and set them to 25-25-25-25 in the field CAP Via etc...
If i remove the doctype it works (i can't remove it because i need it for something else)

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html style ="height: 100%">
<body>
<table cellpadding=4 align=center width=772 border=1 style="border-collapse:collapse;">
          <tr>
            <td valign=top colspan=4>
              <center>
                <b>INFORMAZIONI CLIENTE</b>
              </center>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align"left" valign=top colspan=4>
              Nome e Cognome del Cliente/Azienda:<br>
              <input type="Text" align="LEFT" size="120">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align"left" valign=top colspan=4>
              Via:
              <br>
              <input type="Text" align="LEFT" size="120">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align"left" valign=top style="width:1%;">
              CAP:
              <br>
              <input type="Text"align="LEFT" size="4">
            </td>
            <td align"left" valign=top style="width:1%;">
              Citt&agrave;:
              <br>
              <input type="Text" align="LEFT" size="65">
            </td>
            <td align"left" valign=top style="width:1%;">
                Prov:
                <br>
                <input type="Text" align="LEFT" size="2">
            </td>
            <td align"left" valign=top style="width:99%;">
              Data:
              <br>
              <input type="Text" align="LEFT" size="1" > / <input type="Text" align="LEFT" size="1" ><nobr> / <input type="Text" align="LEFT" size="4">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align"left" valign=top colspan=4>
              Info aggiuntive
                <br>
                <input type="Text" align="LEFT" size="120">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What widths do the columns get in IE8?

Comment: They adapt to the thext inside of them

Comment: when you tried table-layout:fixed did you set the widths via <col> elements? If you only specify the widths on the 4th row, they will be ignored. Only first row cells or col elements can affect the widths of a fixed layout table. But in your case, with the colspan=4 in the first row I think you have to use col elements

Comment: If i delete the all the text except the one inside the Data: < td> and set the dimensions of the row like this 99%-1%-1%-1%, the last < td> is larger than the other and the one setted to 99% is slightly larger than the other 2 setted at 1%

Comment: i've never used < col> elements, i'll give it a try.

Comment: Thank you dgrogan your < col> method helped a lot, I've had some issue with another table but the problem was the width of the entire table that was not setted. Thank you again.